# Tree view with check all or uncheck all in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I used the following code to make a tree in knockout.js with multi level data.

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: $data.items }"></ul>

<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <input type='checkbox'>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: $data.items }">

        </ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

but now i want to extend this in knockout in that way that if i checked parent then all its children got selected and if uncheck parent  children get unchecked.

**`Here is js fiddle link`**

http://jsfiddle.net/tEGUp/

Comment: Your checkboxes aren't data-bound to anything.  Are you trying to just show a check or is there actually a checked property??

Comment: my checkboxes are used to activate and deactivate that node in db , i means they are databound.

Comment: @rahularyansharma so in the reality your checkbox looks something like `<input type='checkbox' data-bind="checked: isChecked'>` and you have a `isChecked` like `ko.observable` property on every item?

Comment: no yet .. i have paste my data also in jsfiddle .

Comment: If you would have a `isChecked` on your items then you could have a root level `click` handler where you could recursively check uncheck your lower level items... something like: http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/RrvXG/

Comment: @nemesv great work, i just found one issue that in case i checked morphed and then remove check from 5 day then , that morphed also should be un checked. but really great work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a version that does not alter the orginal data but uses KO mapping.

I also took the opertunity to show how much less code you need to write with my Convention library

```
MyApp.TreeViewModel = function(data) {
    var mapping = {
        items: {
            create: function(options) {
                return new MyApp.TreeViewModel(options.data);
            }
        }
    };
    this.checked = ko.observable(false); 
    this.checked.subscribe(this.onChecked, this);

    this.items = ko.observableArray();

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);     
};

MyApp.TreeViewModel.prototype = {
    constructor: MyApp.TreeViewModel,
    onChecked: function(checked) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items(), function(item) {
            item.checked(checked);
        });
    }
};
```

- With my lib http://jsfiddle.net/u28CY/
- Without http://jsfiddle.net/u28CY/1/

Comment: i just found one issue that in case i checked morphed and then remove check from 5 day then , that morphed also should be un checked

Comment: You can use options.parent in create function to add the parent to the child, when uncheckign the child, uncheck the parent

Comment: Is it possible for you to edit your code as i am new to knockout.js

Comment: I just say you are champ of KO .